# show this sum $\sum_{i<j\le p-1}\frac{1}{ij} $is divide p

Tags: number-theory

let $p>3$ prime number,show that
$$\sum_{1\le i<j\le p-1,2\ \nmid\ i,2\ |\ j}\dfrac{1}{ij}\equiv0\pmod p$$

it seem maybe can use well konwn $$P|H_{p-1}$$
where $H_{n}=1+\dfrac{1}{2}+\dfrac{1}{3}+\cdots+\dfrac{1}{n}$

[parigp code](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/gp.html) `p=17; sum(i=1,p-1,sum(j=1,p-1,1/Mod(i*j,p)*(Mod(i,2)==1)*(Mod(j,2)==0)*(i<j)))`

Comment: Is it the sum of $\frac{1}{ij}$ or the sum of $(ij)^{-1}$?Those are different things because of the modular arithmetic.... The one you wrote is probably not even an integer.

Comment: @N.S.That's mean

Comment: What do you mean that that is mean? Does $\frac{1}{ij}$ means the rational number or the inverse of $(ij)$ in the modulop p group?

Comment: Note that for $n \geq 2$, $H_n$ is NOT an integer.

Comment: @N.S. You can interpret the sum as being in $\Bbb{Z}_{(p)}/(p)$ where $\Bbb{Z}_{(p)}$ is the ring of rational numbers with denominator coprime to $p$.

Comment: @reuns,you mean is right,Thanks

Comment: @N.S. As reuns points out, you can interpret a rational number mod $n$ whenever the denominator is a unit mod $n$. In this setting $xy$ and $x+y$ mod $n$ can be evaluated in two ways: doing the multiplication or addition as rational numbers, then turning into a residue, or vice-versa. The results are the same, so we can say sum of $1/(ij)$ or the sum of $(ij)^{-1}$. I'm guessing you know this, and are guessing OP doesn't, but in that case I think it needs to be pointed out.

Comment: @reuns No, but $(p-i)j=-ij$ and $p-i\ne j$ in the conditions (since $i+j=p$ would imply one of $i,j$ is even). I guess we need to care about $i<j$ and possible reordering though.

Comment: Since $2$ is invertible mod $p$, what does $2\nmid i$ and $2\mid j$ mean?

Comment: @robjohn You could equally well ask that about $1\le i<j\le p-1$, since inequalities don't exist mod $p$. The summing condition is presumably evaluated before interpreting mod $p$.

Answer (score 3):

All the fractions are to be interpreted as modular inverse modulo $p$.

For $2|j$ and $1<j\leq p-1$, we use $\frac1j+\frac1{p-j}=\frac p{j(p-j)}$. Then we have

$$-S:=-\sum_{1\leq i<j\leq p-1, \ 2\nmid i, \ 2|j} \frac1{ij}\equiv \sum_{1\leq i<j\leq p-1, \ 2\nmid i, \ 2|j} \frac1{i(p-j)} \ \mathrm{mod} \ p.$$

Then we apply a change of variable $(i,p-j) \mapsto (i,j)$, we now consider
$$
-S\equiv \sum_{1\le i, j \le p-1, \ i+j<p, \ 2\nmid i, \ 2\nmid j} \frac1{ij} \ \mathrm{mod} \  p.
$$

We have the above sum is
$$
\sum_{i,j \ \mathrm{odd}, \ i+j<p} \frac1{i+j}\left(\frac1i+\frac1j\right) = 2\sum_{i,j\ \mathrm{odd}, \ i+j<p} \frac1{(i+j)i}\equiv 2S \ \mathrm{mod} \ p.
$$

Thus, $-S\equiv 2S$ mod $p$ gives $3S\equiv 0$ mod $p$. Hence $S\equiv 0$ mod $p$.

Comment: That it failed for $p=3$ was a good hint that we wanted $-S = 2S$